# Video drawn on HTML canvas only plays in chrome, even with webm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, canvas

I am drawing a video to a canvas and then drawing another image on top of it with a blend mode. So far my video works on chrome but not on firefox or safari. When I open with Firefox I see the blended canvas for a second and then it disappears. When I look in safari it shows the top image (which is a face)

I have an mp4 and a webm video uploaded to my website and when I inspect the code and show the video I can see that it is actually playing in firefox, which is confusing because it is like it has found the image and video data?

Is there something I need to do to get the video to work on all browsers?

Below is the code I am using and here is a link to the website (only works as supposed to in chrome at the moment) - http://chrisgjones.com/category/double-exposure/

```
    var img1 = document.getElementById('img1'),
    bg = document.getElementById('img2'),
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    video  = document.getElementById('video');
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    blendMode = "multiply";

context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";   // dont apply blending to bg image

video.addEventListener('play', function () {
    var $this = this; //cache
    (function loop() {
        if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended) {
            context.drawImage($this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30); // drawing at 30fps
            context.globalCompositeOperation = blendMode;
            context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
        }
    })();
}, 0);

$(window).load(function(){
    video.play();
});
```

Comment: You will have to deliver different video encodings for different browsers:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats.

Comment: Yes I have a webm, I can even have the video playing on the website when it is just html. The problem seems to arise when I take the image data and transfer it to the canvas?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean setInterval instead of setTimeout. But anyway, better use requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have never used requestAnimationFrame before and am not really sure how to implement it with what I have but thanks I will give that a go!